# Filter on month and date irrespective of year in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column of data one of them being a date and am expected to drop the rows that have leap dates. It is a range of years so I was hoping to drop any that matched the 02-29 filter.

The one way I used is to add additional columns, extract the month and date separately and then filter on the data as shown below. It serves the purpose but obviously not good from an efficiency perspective

```
df['Yr'], df['Mth-Dte'] = zip(*df['Date'].apply(lambda x: (x[:4], x[5:])))
df = df[df['Mth-Dte'] != '02-29']
```

Is there a better way to implement this by directly applying the filter on the column in the dataframe?

Adding the data

```
        ID          Date
22398   IDM00096087 1/1/2005
22586   IDM00096087 1/1/2005
21790   IDM00096087 1/2/2005
21791   IDM00096087 1/2/2005
14727   IDM00096087 1/3/2005
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share some data? You should convert to datetime: pd.to_datetime() and filter away using .dt.month == 2 & .dt.day == 29. If it is years you could simply use mod (%).

Comment: Thanks. I am still learning this. I figured I could use the datetime function but couldn't come up with a way to write it out in a single statement like the way you mention

Comment: Np, but what is it you need to remove? February 29 only?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. I just need to ignore the leap dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to datetime and use boolean mask.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': {14727: '1/3/2005',
  21790: '1/2/2005',
  21791: '1/2/2005',
  22398: '1/1/2005',
  22586: '29/2/2008'},
 'ID': {14727: 'IDM00096087',
  21790: 'IDM00096087',
  21791: 'IDM00096087',
  22398: 'IDM00096087',
  22586: 'IDM00096087'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Option1, convert + dt:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

# Filter away february 29
df[~((df.Date.dt.month == 2) & (df.Date.dt.day == 29))] # ~ for not equal to
```

Option2, convert + strftime:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

# Filter away february 29
df[df.Date.dt.strftime('%m%d') != '0229']
```

Option3, without conversion:

```
mask = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime('%m%d') != '0229'
df[mask]
```

Comment: Awesome... Thanks!! That is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @rajeev added option without the need to make datetime column

Comment: The second option for someone like me looks a little too complex. Will take some time to digest that.

Comment: @rajeev I simplified the strftime alternatives. If that could be any help for future operations. Happy New Year.

Comment: I actually understood the first one you wrote yesterday. Made a ton of sense when you go back and re-read it. This one is simpler as well. you just taught me 3 ways to solve it. Appreciate all the help